# Are chaincode input parameters stored in the blockchain?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, privacy

As described [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/ledger/ledger.html#transactions), the input parameters comprises a field in the transaction, which will be added to a block and then finally chained to the blockchain.

So, from that, can I assume that all input parameters are visible to all peers from that channel? Or, in other words, is it correct to say that it's not a good practice to use sensitive data as input parameters?

Am I right in this assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposal request (which includes the chaincode name, function and parameters) is included in the proposal response which is included in the transaction submitted for ordering and eventually committed in a block.

There is a "transient" field you can use with proposal requests which is not included in the final transaction sent to the ledger.